# how to resolve the error appears in pom.xml when creating a new maven project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, pom.xml

I installed Eclipse on my mac and created a new maven project but there's an error on the pom.xml file says: *Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration:

> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile
> (execution: default-testCompile, phase: test-compile)*

I tried installing a new version of Eclipse but I faced the same.

[image]

Comment: You should know that Maven loads and executes some default plugins even if they are not written in the pom.xml file. it seems that the maven-compiler-plugin has a problem with your settings in the file. Show your pom.xml file.

Comment: Right click project "pom.xml" in eclipse and select "Maven Install".

Comment: If above didn't work then you can try deleting the maven-compiler-plugin folder from your .m2 directory. The path should look like .m2/repository/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin

Comment: @Stefan the screenshot shows the pom file

Comment: @Aman option "Maven Install" does not exist in the menu

Comment: and regarding the path, I'm new to mac so I don't know where to find the start point of .m2

Comment: 0

Maybe you are using an old Maven version. The plugin repository does not support HTTP anymore since last winter, but HTTP is used by older maven version by default. Did you try to delete the local cache folder as Aman suggested? The .m2 folder is inside your home folder. You can run the "mvn install" command in a terminal window.

Comment: Thanks @Stefan, for your follow up. I deleted the .m2 folder and then maven -> update project but the error still exists.